# Proof that a circle and a triangle are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Where can I find the proof that a circle and a triangle are homotopic ?
Is it easy to prove it if we consider $X$ to be the unit circle $e^{ix},x\in [0,2\pi]$ and $Y$ to be a triangle lets say $Y=x(1,0)+x(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})+x(2,0), x\in[0,1]$
how can we show that $H:X \times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $H(x,0)=e^{ix}$ and  $H(x,1)=Y$ for every x?

Comment: Regarding the title, homotopy makes no sense for sets, only for _pairs of mappings from one space to another_ possibly subject to additional conditions such as fixing the image of one point. <> You have two mappings from $[0, 1]$ into the complex plane, $f$ tracing a circle and $g$ tracing a triangle. Your task is to _construct_ a homotopy $H$. The standard idiom in this situation is to connect $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ by a line segment as $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$. It's then easy to check the required properties of $H$.

Comment: Consider the unit circle $S^1$ and a triangle $T$ circumscribed to $S^1$ (it's easier to visualize the homotopy). Let $f:[0,1]\ni t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be the parameterization of the triangle $T$, then define $H:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb C $ as $$H(t,s)=f(s)(1-t)+g(s)t$$ this homotopy continuously deform the parameterization of the unit circle into the parameterization of the triangle